# Error when adding an action to a pin in map view

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am trying to make an application where various pins are placed on the map.

When I touch a pin, the standard bubble pops up with a disclosure button. When I click my disclosure button, I would like it to open up a new ViewController so I can display more information.

The problem is that every time I run the application, it crashes and it gives me an error in the output.

How could I fix this?

The error in the output is:

> 2013-06-29 16:51:33.575 ...[2723:13d03] -[FirstViewController
>   ...Clicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x867d0d0
>   2013-06-29 16:51:33.576 lam[2723:13d03] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[FirstViewController ...Clicked:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x867d0d0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1d8d012 0x11cae7e 0x1e184bd 0x1d7cbbc 0x1d7c94e 0x11de705 0x182c0 0x18258 0xd9021 0xd957f 0xd86e8 0x47cef
>   0x47f02 0x25d4a 0x17698 0x1ce8df9 0x1ce8ad0 0x1d02bf5 0x1d02962
>   0x1d33bb6 0x1d32f44 0x1d32e1b 0x1ce77e3 0x1ce7668 0x14ffc 0x1e12
>   0x1d45) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

The code in my FirstViewController.m is:

```
[...]

[...]

-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"..."]) {
        [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(...Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"..."]) {
        [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(...Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
    MyPin.draggable = NO;
    MyPin.highlighted = YES;
    MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return MyPin;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView MyPin:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    // Go to edit view
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"...Controller" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}


//-(void) ...Clicked:(id)sender {

  //  NSLog(@"... Clicked");
//}


-(void) ...:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"...");
}


-(IBAction)findmylocation:(id)sender {

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];

}
```

What causes the error is:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView MyPin:(MKPinAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    // Go to edit view
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"..." bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT 2: 
I have removed the advertButton addTarget lines, but now I don't have the disclosure button when I run the simulator... is what I removed correct?

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"..."])

    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"..."])
```

Comment: What is the exact crash message?  Show the code that is executed when the disclosure button is tapped.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I just update the question with the code and complete error code... Thank you for your time!

Comment: dcb: please rephrase because there is no lldb error here. there is a  error in YOUR app and pretty easy one.. lldb is the debugger and it is just telling you about the error. anna got it right

Comment: @Daij-Djan yes.. I was getting a lldb error when I posted this question, but then I took away the breakpoints and the error code was different. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error:

> [FirstViewController ...Clicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

means that it's trying to call the `...Clicked:` method on `FirstViewController` (because you set the `advertButton`'s target to that method) but there is no such method (you've commented it out).

You *could* just un-comment it.

But since you are using the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method anyway to detect accessory taps (a better choice than a custom method), you should instead do the following:

***Remove*** the `advertButton  addTarget` lines from `viewForAnnotation` and just handle the taps in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`.

Also remove the `...Clicked:` method.

Another issue is the method `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is incorrectly named as `mapView:MyPin:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`.

The method ***must*** be named `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    // Go to edit view
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"...Controller" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

By the way, in the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, you'll be able to access the annotation that was tapped through `view.annotation`.

The updated `viewForAnnotation` should be something like this:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
    MyPin.draggable = NO;
    MyPin.highlighted = YES;
    MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return MyPin;
}
```

Comment: @DCB, Please _add_ the updated method to the Question (edit it).  Do not remove the original code from the Question -- just add the changes at the bottom.  Long code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: I put an example of the suggested change into the answer.

Comment: in other words, how do I control which annotation was tapped with the view.annotation command?

Comment: In the calloutAccessoryControlTapped method, remember that `view.annotation` is the annotation object.  So you can do something like `if ([view.annotation.title isEqualToString:@"abcd"]) ...`.  Try it out and if still not working or need more help, start a new question about it.

Comment: Hello Anna, it's me again haha do you know how to use storyboards and nibs in the same project? I have created a question a few days back but no response. I am making a tabbed application with 2 tabs nib and 1 tab storyboard. Is this possible?

Comment: @DCB, I haven't used storyboards but you probably can use it with xibs in the same project.  I have added the iOS tag to your question.  Maybe there was no response because people who look for the iOS tag didn't see it.